# VertexRDD giving me type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am running the following code attempting to create a Graph in GraphX in Apache Spark.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader 

import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId

//loads file from the array

val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://moonshot-ha-nameservice/data/google-plus/2309.graph");

//maps lines and takes the first 21 characters of each line which is the node.

val result = lines.map( line => line.substring(0,20))

//creates a new variable with each node followed by a long .

val result2 = result.map(word => (word,1L).toLong)

//where i am getting an error

val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long,Long)] = sc.parallelize(result2)
```

**i am getting the following error:**

```
 error: type mismatch;

 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Long)]

 required: Seq[?]

Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
         val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, Long)] = sc.parallelize(result2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your maps can be simplified to the following code:

```
val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, Long)] = 
  lines.map(line => (line.substring(0, 17).toLong, 1L))
```

Now, to your error: you cannot call `sc.parallelize` with an RDD. Your vertexRDD is already defined by result2. You can then create your graph with result2 and your EdgesRDD:

```
val g = Graph(result2, edgesRDD)
```

or, if using my suggestion:

```
val g = Graph(vertexRDD, edgesRDD)
```

Comment: when i run your code i get the following:                                                                                                           (0 + 9) / 59]16/12/16 18:12:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 126, moon07.eecs.qmul.ac.uk): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10867043655226952823"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:592)
 at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
 at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
 ......

Comment: @RhysCopperthwaite Oh, sure, the maximum Long value has 19 chars, so your substring should limit it to 18 to be sure. GraphX does not support vertices with strings as ID, so you must have a numeric ID that fits in a Long value. You can also try a `line.hashCode()` instead of `line.substring()` if you want.

Comment: @RhysCopperthwaite using `hashCode()` might not be the best way to define the ID. You need to make sure each node has a distinct numeric ID which could fit in a Long variable.